# Отрицательный оператор LOCATE в sql запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

в sql есть оператор LOCATE() для поиска подстроки в столбце базы данных

```
SELECT * FROM magazin WHERE LOCATE('стол',text) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

есть ли какой то противоположный оператор? если этот работает на "поле содержит подстроку" как можно сделать запрос наоборот "поле не должно содержать подстроку"?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM magazin WHERE text NOT LIKE '%стол%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> в sql есть оператор LOCATE() для поиска подстроки в столбце базы данных
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM magazin WHERE LOCATE('стол',text) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
> ```

Ну, во-первых, это таки функция, а не оператор.

Во-вторых, в приведённом коде она используется вовсе не для поиска подстроки.

Как именно работает код?

Если подстрока есть - функция возвращает её смещение от начала. Смещение - целое число от 1 и более. При использовании во WHERE любое такое число интерпретируется как TRUE.

Если подстроки нет - функция возвращает ноль. При использовании во WHERE ноль интерпретируется как FALSE.

Если хотя бы один из параметров NULL - функция вернёт NULL. Во WHERE NULL интерпретируется как FALSE.

Как инвертировать действие? обычным оператором (на сей раз - действительно оператором) `NOT` (или его синонимом `!`). Он превратит TRUE в FALSE, а FALSE соответственно в TRUE. А вот NULL так и останется NULL.

Так что

```
SELECT * 
FROM magazin 
WHERE !LOCATE('стол',text) 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```